# My (wide) page looks weird on low resolutions

Tags: css

I am having a little trouble getting my page that has the width 900px look ok on resolutions where the width is *lower* than 900px. That includes mobile devices such as smartphones. It looks like im zoomed in on the page, but without the ability to scroll around or zoom out. My page wrapper is defined to be centered at the screen. Here is the CSS for the wrapper

```
#wrapper{
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
margin-left:-450px;
width: 900px;
min-height: 100%;
height: auto;
}
```

Comment: Are you using a meta tag for the viewport? i.e. user-resizable or max-scale?

Comment: do you need scroll bar's css?

Comment: I didn't know it existed. It seems like what im looking for. But how should i set it so that automatically scales so that the whole page fit's the screen? If i set initial-scale to 1 it looks good on devices with a width of 900px and higher, but still same problem on devices with lower resolutions.

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=900,initial-scale:1">

Comment: Still zoomed in on my HTC Desire (Yes a clear the cache between the tests)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do it like this:

```
body {
    min-width: 900px;
}
```

Will also solve your issues on devices other than smartphones.

-edit-

To solve your initial scaling issue, add the <meta> for viewport ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag ) :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1000">
```

Comment: Now i'm able to zoom out on my phone to see the whole page, but it won't solve the initial scaling issue

Comment: But the initial-scale should be different for different devices, and if the initial-scale is 1 for a page with width 900px on a device with a width of 480px, then the scaling should be around 0.5, what is the best way to solve that?

Comment: Oops, sorry, you should be able to simply remove the initial-scale parameter.

Comment: It looks good on my iPad, scales correctly from the beginning. Gonna check how i looks on iPhone, but still scales wrong on Android.

Comment: Turned out it was only mi Android rom that had problem viewing my page, works on all other Android builds =) Thank you guys for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: That won't solve the scaling issue, still zoomed in from the beginning :/

Comment: @Scott I suggest you read the [faq] and [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). Code should be formatted as code.